# How to get value of a Yes/No checkbox control when passed to another class?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form `TForm` based on table `T`.  There is a Yes/No field `Choice` in `T`.  To add this field to `TForm`, I added a checkbox `ChoiceCheck` to the form.  I am trying to get `ChoiceCheck`'s value in another class, `SQLPreparer`, which I am using to construct SQL statements based on values in `TForm`:

```
Private Function controlToValueStr(ctrl As Control) As String

If ctrl.name = "ChoiceCheck" Then
    controlToValueStr = ctrl.Value
Else
    'return the control's value wrapped in quote marks
    controlToValueStr = quoteWrap(ctrl.Value)
End If

End Function
```

However, when I call `SQLPreparer.controlToValueStr()` and pass `ChoiceCheck`, the `ctrl.Value` statement gives me this error:

```
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I'm able to get the value in the class for `TForm` itself as follows:

```
Me.ChoiceCheck.Value
```

All of the text box controls of type string work in both situations.  I'm also having this problem with a textbox whose type in `T` is a Long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the I had named the **label** `ChoiceCheck`, not the checkbox itself.  The same issue was present with the textbox.  In both cases, changing the control names in Design View to match the VBA code resolved the issue.

Comment: Yes, it works because VBA is weakly typed and a function returning `String` can be assigned an `Integer` value.  E.g. if `ctrl` has a value of 0, `controlToValueStr` will return "0".